# Marking a function as async but no await calls, any issues?

Tags: c#, async-await

Are there any side effects to having a function that is marked as async, but it doesn't actually make any await calls? Eg:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    Task DoSomethingAsync();
}

public class DoSomething1:IMyInterface
{
    public async Task DoSomethingAsync()
    {
        await getSomethingFromDatabaseAsync();
    }
}

public class DoSomething2:IMyInterface
{
    public async Task DoSomethingAsync()
    {
        doSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

IMyInterface is implemented by quite a few classes, but for one of the classes there are no **await** calls. Will this cause any problems?

Comment: Why mark it as async?

Comment: Because to implement the interface the function needs to have the word Async on the end, and I think it's confusing to have a method that ends in Async but actually isn't.  I'm wondering if that will cause any problems.

Comment: If it were me I would just remove the `Async()` suffix from the method name. If the method is not guaranteed to be async, it's maybe not appropriate. It is enough for the caller to know that the method returns a `Task` and that it is not complete unless `IsCompleted` is true.

Comment: **Do not use `async` on a method that has no `await`s.** The *only* purpose of `async` is to inform the compiler that you intend to use `await`. **If you do not have that intention then do not mark methods as `async`.**  Whether or not there are "side effects is **completely irrelevant**. Whether or not it will "cause problems" is **irrelevant**.  The `async` is there as a marker that `await` will be used. **If you are not using `await` then there is typically no reason to mark a method as `async`**.

Comment: I note that if you do this, **you will get a compiler warning telling you to not do that**.  Pay attention to the compiler warnings. **We added those warnings for a reason**. The reason is that `async` should be used only to indicate that `await` is being used, so if there is an `async` without an `await`, *someone is doing something wrong*.

Comment: Thanks very much Eric, I guess I am seeking to understand the reason why those warnings were added and what effect it will have on my application. Maybe you consider it irrelevant, but I think that's a bit unfair, I just want to learn why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> IMyInterface is implemented by quite a few classes, but for one of the classes there are no await calls. Will this cause any problems?

I'm going to enter dangerous territory here and disagree with Eric Lippert. In the vast majority of cases, using `async` without `await` is indeed a mistake and the compiler warning is useful. I'd say this is true well north of 90% of the time.

However, I'd say this scenario is an exception to that rule. The problem with just dropping `async`/`await` is that exceptions are handled quite differently:

```
public Task DoSomethingAsync()
{
  // if doSomethingElse throws, that exception is raised directly;
  // it is *not* captured and placed on the returned task!
  doSomethingElse();
  return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

The expected semantics for a `Task`-returning method is that exceptions are captured and placed on the returned `Task` (well, at least non-[bone-headed](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/) exceptions). To keep these semantics, you need to either use `async` (and suppress the warning) or an explicit `try`/`catch`:

```
#pragma warning disable 1998
public async Task DoSomethingAsync()
#pragma warning restore 1998
{
  doSomethingElse();
}

// or

public Task DoSomethingAsync()
{
  try
  {
    doSomethingElse();
    return Task.CompletedTask;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    return Task.FromException(ex);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much SC, and thanks for all of your great articles on async/await. I have read them all multiple times :)

Comment: I was hopping for this answer to materialize, its a great point about the exception i missed. Would you find yourself using the *async* approach much? im guessing it would only start to make sense when efficiency was not a big problem, and one big overriding catch block wasn't suitable, though even then i tend to be allergic to disable pragma's

Comment: Historically, I've sided more with Eric Lippert and really avoided the `async`-with-pragma approach. But more recently, I've used that technique more, even [making it a part of AsyncEx (prerelease)](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/db32fd5db0d1051e867b36ae039ea13d2c36eb91/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Tasks/TaskHelper.cs).

Answer (score 7):

In the case where you have an interface method that returns a task and you have no awaits (yeah it happens). Just remove the `async` keyword and return [`Task.CompletedTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.completedtask?view=netframework-4.7.2)

The `Task.CompletedTask` property returns a task whose `Status` property is set to `RanToCompletion`.

> Gets a task that has already completed successfully.

```
public class DoSomething2:IMyInterface
{
    public Task DoSomethingAsync()
    {
        doSomethingElse();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Yes there are side affects, the compiler is plumbing up the IAsyncStateMachine and produces a bunch more *IL*, additionally future developers will look at your code with *ire*. As for other functional differences, I can't think of any off hand.

Comment: That's a good workaround but doesn't answer my question, without it will it cause problems?

Comment: @Rocklan you don't need `async` keyword, the only reason why that keyword exists is so that you can use `await`. If you're not using `await`, there is no reason to mark it `async`. This is the right solution for your use case.

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @Rocklan Using `async` when you're not `await`ing anything is pointless i.e. no, it won't cause any problems. I'm still puzzled why you want to add `async`, your interface doesn't enforce it

Comment: @vasily.sib Where are you getting that from? That is not the question

Comment: @JohanP sorry, my mistake. I just read the question again and can't figure out where I got this from:)

Answer (score -2):

In your case, I think there might be a problem of blocking the main thread (and it depends if you care or not) and I think this is not a developer wants.

If you do not have any await calls, you can do the below so that the main thread will not be blocked (> .net 4.0):

```
public class DoSomething2:IMyInterface
{
     public async Task DoSomethingAsync()
     {
         await Task.Run(()=>doSomethingElse());
     }
}
```